# Ajax Get request using anchor to send requests - not sending variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this php code that retrieves information from the database depending on what image ID is present. It works fine, now I'm trying to turn this into an ajax request so it loads onto the one page. I'm struggling to send the variable through, the ajax request seems to work fine in that it is sending to the page and retrieving the information but it's not sending the variable through so the information returned is blank.

I've been following tutorial and trying to adapt it for my needs and starting to fall apart with it towards the end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my html:

```
//these anchors are meant to send the value attribute through the ajax using showEp()
//I believe it's here that the request is falling down.
<a href="#" value="<?php echo $ep['ep_id'];?>" onclick="showEp(this.value)"><img src="images/Database/releases/<?php 
    if(isset($ep['ep_img'])){
        echo $ep['ep_img'];
    } else {
        echo 'no_EP.png';
    }
    ?> " height="125" width="125"/></a>
<div id="ep"></div>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
function showEp(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("ep").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("ep").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","showep.php?ep_id="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
return false; // to disable the link from following it's href.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I found was using the `value` attribute which isn't actually an attribute of an anchor tag - correct me if I'm wrong.

After some extra research I found that if I used the `name` attribute then it worked fine.

Here's the amended code:

```
<a href="#" name="<?php echo $ep['ep_id'];?>" onclick="showEp(this.name)"><img      src="images/Database/releases/<?php 
if(isset($ep['ep_img'])){
    echo $ep['ep_img'];
} else {
    echo 'no_EP.png';
}
?> " height="125" width="125"/></a>
```

I still need to prevent the default action of the link but I'm happy enough that the ajax function is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if(isset($ep['ep_img'])){
    $img = $ep['ep_img'];
} else {
    $img = 'no_EP.png';
}
?>

<a href="#" value="<?php echo $ep['ep_id'];?>" onclick="showEp(this.value)">
    <img src="images/Database/releases/<?php echo $img;?>" height="125" width="125"/>
</a>
```